# How Digital search trees Work?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I have tried many online sources but i am unable to understand how digital binary search tree works.Below Link is the example for your reference
(LINK: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~kube/cls/100/Lectures/lec15/lec15-10.html)

Is anybody construct a tree using these values and tell in detail that how it works?

```
A   00001
S   10011
E   00101
R   10010
C   00011
H   10100
```

Comment: From your own link: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~kube/cls/100/Lectures/lec15/lec15-3.html#pgfId-968641 What part of that explanation is not clear?

Comment: I understood now that how searching is working but still not clear about: when we traverse the tree for Element H(10100) using bits 101 and then we match other two bits(00) and then we found Element H but while we are inserting elements into tree,Can we make our own digital sequence? use reference: cseweb.ucsd.edu/~kube/cls/100/Lectures/lec15/lec15-10.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tree is constructed in such a way that the binary representations of the keys (`A`,`S`,`E`,`R`,`C`,`H`) can be used to locate them into the tree. In each searching step, the key is compared to the curren node (which is the root of the current search three). If the the key is not the root, the most significant bit of the key's binary representation is used to select the left subree (if the bit is `0`) or the right subtree (if the bit is `1`). This process is explained in more detail [here](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/Teaching/COMP317B/Week_4/digital_search_tree.html).

In the example you provided, the key `H` (binary representation `10100`) can be found as follows.

1. In the first step, the root is node `A`. As `A` does not equal `H`, the bit `1` is used, indicating that the right subtree should be chosen. Consequently, we consider the node `S` and the bit string `0100` which results from the original binary representation by omission of the most significant bit.
2. Since `A` does not equal `H`, we use the most significant bit, which is `0`, indicating a choice of the left subtree. We consider the node `R` and the bit string `100`.
3. As `R` does not equal `H`, again we use the most significant bit, which is `1`, which means that the right subtree is to be chosen. We consider the node `H` and the bit string `00`.
4. Since `H` equals `H`, we have found the desired key and the search terminates.

Comment: Thanks for reply 
I understood now that how searching is working but still not clear about: 
when we traverse the tree for Element H(10100) using bits 101 and then we match other two bits(00) and then we found Element H but while we are inserting elements into tree,Can we make our own digital sequence?
use reference: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~kube/cls/100/Lectures/lec15/lec15-10.html

Comment: It's not so clear from the description. I would guess that the binary sequences for the keys must be of same length and distinct; insertion apparently works by traversing the tree in the same manner (`0` means branch to left child, `1` means branch to right child) until a `null` reference is found, where the key is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

The DST works like by checking the bit level by level. Checks the starting of the bit if o then moves to left or else to right. At the same time it compares the bit position with the level.

For example:
Root is in the O level,

- if the bit to be inserted is in the 1 st level then checks the 1st bit,
- if 0 then inserts as a left or if it is 1 then insert in the right.

Similarly for the second level, checks the second bit to be inserted and works like this for the remaining levels.

In the given example;

First A (00001) is a root node, then S(10011) since 1 , move to the right  and inserted.

The next is E(00101) , since 0 moves to left and inserted, next in the sequence is R(10010), since 1 move to the right , the bit in the second position is 0 so it is inserted as a left child of S.

In the sequence next is C(00011), 0 so moves to the left since 2nd bit is 0 insert in the left side, next is H(10100), since it starts with 1, moves to right, it has to be inserted as 3rd level so check the 3rd bit position as it is with 1, it is inserted in the right.

Hope this will clear your doubt.
 So the final DST looks like this
[DST]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iet4n.gif